# Curvatures preserved under the Kahler-Ricci flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, parabolic-pde, kahler-ricci-flow

Maybe it is a trivial question.  Is there any obvious reason that non-negative holomorphic bisectional curvature is preserved by (normalized) Kahler-Ricci flow, but non-negative Ricci curvature is not preserved by Kahler Ricci flow? More precisely, how can I see it explicitly from the maximum principle argument?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are asking the question on a compact Kahler manifold. You can find argument in Mok's paper for the part of non-negativity of holomorphic bisectional curvature (HBSC) is preserved under Kahler Ricci flow.(http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214441778)
 Roughly speaking, we need to compute the evolution equation of HBSC, then we will get a quadratic term involving curvature besides the heat operator. If the quadratic term satisfies "null vector condition", then the maximal principle will get us the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is the conjecture of Feldman:
The answer is in the page 207 of this book: The Ricci Flow: Techniques and Applications: Part II: Analytic Aspects

[See here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1vXGVcMYJWgC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=non-negative%20Ricci%20curvature%20is%20not%20preserved%20by%20Kahler%20Ricci%20flow&source=bl&ots=zmHTzSz6v6&sig=z9yz64Zyz8iZD5so4fnOnQNc5GQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=T71LVMCIFMngavfZgtAD&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=non-negative%20Ricci%20curvature%20is%20not%20preserved%20by%20Kahler%20Ricci%20flow&f=false)